# Tell whether each function is a sinusoid and explain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have that sinusoids have the form $f(x)=a_1\sin[b(x-h_1)]+a_2\cos[b(x-h_2)]$.

I want to show whether 
$y=\cos(4x-3)+\cos(4x+2)$ is a sinusoid and explain.

Is it not a sinusoid because one term has to have a $\sin$?

Comment: Show your working so far. It'll both help you and encourage others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $y=\cos(4x-3)+\cos(4x+2)$ is a sinusoid by writing it in the form $f(x)=a_1\sin[b(x-h_1)]+a_2\cos[b(x-h_2)]$.

$$
\begin{align}
y &= \cos(4x-3)+\cos(4x+2)
\\ &= \cos[-(4x-3)]+\cos(4x+2) \text{$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ (Because $\cos(-\theta) =\cos (\theta)$)}
\\ &= \cos(-4x+3)+\cos(4x+2)
\\ &= \sin\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-(-4x+3)\right]+\cos(4x+2) \text{$\;\;\;$(Because $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = \cos(\theta)$)}
\\ &= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+4x-3\right)+\cos(4x+2)
\\ &= \sin\left(4x+\frac{\pi}{2}-3\right)+\cos(4x+2)
\\ &= \sin\left[4\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-3\right)\right)\right]+\cos\left[4\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] \text{ $\;\;\;($Factoring out $b$, which is 4)}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, $y=\cos(4x-3)+\cos(4x+2)$ is a sinusoid.